# Making telegram bot inline keyboards in the desired row numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram-bot

I want to make inline keyboards in a telegram bot in two or more rows, I know how to make them in one row (in the following codes):

> ```
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(txtBody.Text);
>
>     int chatId="123456789"; //not real Chat ID
>
>
>     // Buttons
>     InlineKeyboardButton urlButton1 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
>     InlineKeyboardButton urlButton2 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
>     InlineKeyboardButton urlButton3 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
>
>     urlButton1.Text = "Go URL1";
>     urlButton1.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
>
>     urlButton2.Text = "Go URL2";
>     urlButton2.Url = "https://www.bing.com/";
>
>     urlButton3.Text = "Go URL3";
>     urlButton3.Url = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
>
>     InlineKeyboardButton[] buttons = new InlineKeyboardButton[] { urlButton1, urlButton2 , urlButton3};
>     InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons);
>
>     // Send message!
>     bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, sb.ToString(), ParseMode.Html, true, false, 0, inline);
> ```

But how to make the third button in a second row (or the last two buttons in the second row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<InlineKeyboardButton>>` in `InlineKeyboardMarkup` constuctor, And every `IEnumerable<InlineKeyboardButton>` is single row, here is it:

```cs
// Buttons
InlineKeyboardButton urlButton1 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
InlineKeyboardButton urlButton2 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
InlineKeyboardButton urlButton3 = new InlineKeyboardButton();

urlButton1.Text = "Go URL1";
urlButton1.Url = "https://www.google.com/";

urlButton2.Text = "Go URL2";
urlButton2.Url = "https://www.bing.com/";

urlButton3.Text = "Go URL3";
urlButton3.Url = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
    

// Rows, can put multiple buttons!
InlineKeyboardButton[] row1 = new InlineKeyboardButton[] { urlButton1 };
InlineKeyboardButton[] row2 = new InlineKeyboardButton[] { urlButton2, urlButton3 };
    
// Set rows in Array of array | IEnamerable<IEnumerable<InlineKeyboardButton>>
InlineKeyboardButton[][] buttons = new InlineKeyboardButton[][] { row1, row2 };
  
// Keyboard
InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons);

// Send message!
bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, sb.ToString(), ParseMode.Html, true, false, 0, inline);
```